# Anaconda can't install subprocess32

Tags: anaconda, subprocess

How do I install subprocess32 in anaconda?

Ran into this error while trying to install subprocess32 on Anaconda. Please help!

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda install subprocess32
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - subprocess32 -> python[version='2.7.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0']

Your python: python=3

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:



Package vc conflicts for:
subprocess32 -> python=2.7 -> vc[version='>=9,<10.0a0']
python=3 -> vc[version='14.*|>=14,<15.0a0|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
subprocess32 -> vc=9
python=3 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1d,<1.1.2a'] -> vc=9
Package pip conflicts for:
python=3 -> pip
subprocess32 -> python=2.7 -> pip
Package setuptools conflicts for:
subprocess32 -> python=2.7 -> pip -> setuptools
python=3 -> pip -> setuptools
Package wheel conflicts for:
python=3 -> pip -> wheel
subprocess32 -> python=2.7 -> pip -> wheel
Package msgpack-python conflicts for:
subprocess32 -> python=2.7 -> pip -> cachecontrol -> msgpack-python
python=3 -> pip -> cachecontrol -> msgpack-python
```

Trying to install python 2.7 now to see if it will solve the error.

Answer (score 0):

The error has occurred due to dependencies problem. Here `subprocess32` requires python version 2.7. While, you have python version 3.

You can create a new environment with python 2.7 as below:

`conda create --name env1 python=2.7`

activate it:

`conda activate env1`

Then install `subprocess32` as:

`conda install subprocess32`

unfortunately, you may have to reinstall all the other packages.

Comment: Also `subprocess32` is (as far as I'm aware) simply a back-port of `subprocess` from Python3's standard lib. So consider if you actually need Python2, if not simply `import subprocess`, no extra package required.